# Colorize hardlinks in ls output?

Tags: command-line, colors, ls, hard-link

How can I colorize hardlinks myself? Turns out on an old Ubuntu 10.04 I have, this happens by default (same `.bashrc` and `.profile` in use), whereas on the newer Ubuntu 12.04 it doesn't.

This is the output on Ubuntu 10.04 (the one I desire):

[image: Having the colored output for hardlinked files]

And this is the output on Ubuntu 12.04:
[image: Missing the colored output for hardlinked files]

The relevant file is `.vimrc`, however, `.viminfo` is an ordinary file with link count 1, in contrast to the hardlinked `.vimrc`.

Of course the fact that GNU `coreutils` uses texinfo pages instead of man pages doesn't make things easier. I found [this here](http://www.bigbiz.com/cgi-bin/manpage?1%20ls), but it doesn't refer to the case I am looking for.

**TL;DR:** how to achieve coloring hardlinked (as in: link count > 1) files the way I like in various Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @gertvdijk: please, by all means write this up as an answer. Even though it is not the answer I would have liked, this is certainly an authoritative answer on the topic and solves the mystery. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't finding hardlinks a very expensive operation? Do some filesystems provide a reverse lookup or at least a count for links per inode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this:

```
LS_COLORS="mh=44;37" ls -l
```

And you may edit your `~/.profile` to change `LS_COLORS` accordingly.

#### Background

This feature was [enabled as default in 2008](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=1e48b1fee5fa2ad2d1802771eafbfcddb38a24cb) has been [disabled by default in 2009](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=0df338f6719ec2bcf1e1dea2d8b12dc66daf8a1e). Somehow the freeze for Ubuntu 10.04 was exactly in between those moments.

Using the [Git repository of coreutils](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=coreutils) I see that the commit to revert automatic colourization has been in since version 7.5:

```
git tag --contains 0df338f6719ec2bcf1e1dea2d8b12dc66daf8a1e
v7.5
v7.6
[...]
```

In versions before 7.1 there seems no upstream maintained support for this:

```
git tag --contains 1e48b1fee5fa2ad2d1802771eafbfcddb38a24cb
v7.1
v7.2
[...]
```

The source file [`multihardlink.sh`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/tests/ls/multihardlink.sh), lead me to the exact `LS_COLORS` value to enable it again.

You may want to reopen [LP Bug #123423](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/123423).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Spot on. The only trouble right now is how to do this conditionally depending on the version of `coreutils` :)

Comment: @0xC0000022L Updated!

Comment: [In Ubuntu and Debian systems, the default `.bashrc` takes care of setting `$LS_COLORS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544071/20230). Add the following _export_ to the end of `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases` ) to augment `.bashrc`'s default `$LS_COLORS` with gertvdijk's suggestion: `export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:mh=44;37"`

Answer (score 2):

Based on gertvdijk's answer, I came up with the following snippet, which suits my needs:

```
if [[ -e "/etc/debian_version" ]] && type dircolors > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    command dircolors|command grep -q 'hl=' && export LS_COLORS="ln=01;36:hl=00;36"
    command dircolors|command grep -q 'mh=' && export LS_COLORS="ln=01;36:mh=00;36"
fi
```

Edit: I actually had to rewrite the snippet (see edit history).

Turns out that `ls` *swallows* the error output concerning `LS_COLORS` when piping it. At least I couldn't `grep` for it, neither with `2>&1` nor without. Hence the changes. We check for `dircolors` to be available. If it is, it's expected to output a snippet of shell code (Bourne shell compatible by default) that contains the defaults for the various recognized file types. So we check for `hl=` or `mh=` respectively in the output of `dircolors`. This way we can detect which is expected by `ls` and `export LS_COLORS` accordingly. It may be safer to `grep` for `:hl=` and `:mh=` respectively to rule out the possibility for file extensions ending in `hl` or `mh` and matching our condition.

The above colors are light cyan on black for soft links and a darker cyan on default black for hard links.

You can vary the top-level condition, of course. I am currently only setting it on Debian/Ubuntu, because I have no time to test it on older RHEL/CentOS systems at the moment.

NB: the invocations via `command` are to work around potential aliases/functions with the same names as the tools we try to use here.

Comment: `dircolors` is the way to configure this, yes! :)